# Can't Post request to login

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to login a website.I'm using httpwebrequest for post login parameters and then I'm trying to get source code of new page.But it gives me "Bad Request";.
Where is the mistake on my code ?

```
string formUrl = "https://tr.ogame.gameforge.com:443/main/login"; // NOTE: This is the URL the form POSTs to, not the URL of the form (you can find this in the "action" attribute of the HTML's form tag
        string formParams = string.Format("credentials[email]={0}&credentials[password]={1}&autologin={2}&language={3}&kid={4}", "myUsername", "myPassword","false","tr","");
        string cookieHeader;
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
            txtb.Text = pageSource;
        }
```

Here is result i get ;

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
    <html><head>
    <title>400 Bad Request</title>
    </head><body>
    <h1>Bad Request</h1>
    <p>The request could not be understood by the server.</p>
    </body></html>
```

Here is webpage request headers ;
[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBhTk.png)  [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XarWu.png)

Comment: why are you use credentials[email]={0}&credentials[password]={1}?  i think it would be login={0}&pass={1}.

Comment: because its login params as you see in the second pic.

Comment: i analyzed <input>params in <form> tag at login page. but i never seen those parameter name as you wrote.

Comment: So what should i do now?

Comment: The request you are trying is a disallowed. To implement your plan, you should analyze the website protocol in detail. they seems to be prevent auto scrapping already.